# targum-translation tag seems to merge two mostly unrelated tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tags

Why is there only one tag [targum-translation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/targum-translation) for both "Questions about the various Aramaic translations that accompany much of the Jewish Biblical Canon" and "about translation of specific words in Jewish texts"? These are entirely separate classes of questions that are only very loosely (superficially?) related.

Comment: Note that we have [tag:targum-onkelos] too

Answer (score 7):

I support splitting them into:

[targumin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/targumin) Wiki Excerpt: the various Aramaic translations that accompany much of the Jewish Biblical Canon, including Onkelos, Yonaton and Neofiti.

[translation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) Wiki Excerpt: translation of specific words or passages used in Jewish texts and study.

Comment: what would happen to this? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/targum-translation-tag-seems-to-merge-two-mostly-unrelated-tags#comment11864_3878

Comment: @DoubleAA, to the [tag:targum-onkelos] tag? Good question. I suppose it can either be absorbed into the `targumin` tag or the latter's wiki can exclude Onkelus.

Comment: msh210, I support synonimyzing [tag:targum-onkelos] into [tag:targumin]. Most questions about the latter are likely about the former, anyway. I don't see a good reason to get more granular. (@DoubleAA)