# What is the origin of Yat Shevat?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing a lot about Yat Shevat these days; there's a sidebar proclaiming that there's [no Tachanun tomorrow](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69070/), with a link to a very brief exchange on the chat:

> Isaac Moses: Yodeyans, Yod Chet Shevat is hereby designated a minor holiday, for farbrengens and not saying Tachanun.
>
> DoubleAA: @IsaacMoses It was on Yat Shvat in Israel, and that is more catchy.
>
> Isaac Moses: @DoubleAA In ChU"L, we can do both 18 and 19
>   ... or we could do it like Purim and Shushan Purim, and people who want double the revelry can cross the border in the evening.
>
> DoubleAA: @IsaacMoses It has now been designated a Mi Yodeya community event. I'm expecting a detailed Halachic analysis of the rules and regulations of this holiday to be posted on Mi Yodeya sometime in the first two weeks of Adar II.

I'm clearly missing something, as the only thing I see happening on the day of its founding was a [question about the targum-translation tag](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/targum-translation-tag-seems-to-merge-two-mostly-unrelated-tags), [another question about the art and pictures tags](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/vote-to-merge-art-and-pictures-labels), and a question entitled [How and why is sin passed to one's children?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/)

Now, if it were the *17th* of Shevat, I'd say it refers to [this post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/a-newbie-perspective-after-60-days-and-90-qas), which ultimately evolved into our FAQ for new users. As it stands, though, what is the "holiday" celebrating?

Comment: See three lines up in the chat, the quote from Shog9.

Comment: @msh210 “Yeah, ok, done” - with what, exactly? That’s a bit unclear to me.

Comment: The liturgic version of the events is in the [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69077/1569) to the linked question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the day we got the "we don't give rabbinic guidance" notification back, as requested in [this meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883/472) (linked from that chat).

The original Mi Yodeya site (SE 1.0, privately administered) contained the disclaimer.  When we moved onto the SE (2.0) platform we lost it, and for years were told it wasn't possible.  Then later it was possible, and now everybody again sees this:

[image: notice on front page]

The day we got this important piece of site functionality back was declared a minor holiday in *nusach Yodeya*.

Comment: I have to admit .. I know absolutely nothing about "nusach" yodeya ;-) I didn't even know it was a nusach. Now I know what I didn't know, and you know?  I'm still not sure I know.

Comment: @DanF somebody should be able to clear that up for you if you ask in about five weeks.

Comment: @DanF https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100239/